# Error: Unable to access jarfile picard.jar

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables

I have been trying to create a permanent environmental variable to access my `.jar` file from any location. I tried to modify the `.bash_profile` by adding export `PICARD="/Desktop/picard-tools-2.5.0/picard.jar"` and it did not work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "it did not work out" mean specifically?

Comment: It means that I still have the error in the title if I try to run the .jar file from any other location. The command used is: java -jar picard.jar -h

Comment: Because system is looking for the `picard.jar` at the directory at which you were located when launched the script. You need to change working directory in your script. The easiest way is to add `cd $DIR_WHERE_PICARD_JAR_IS_LOCATED` to the beginning of the script.

Comment: Absolutely right, I can do this but my aim is to be able to execute 'java -jar picard.jar -h' from any location without having to refer to the original directory before!